# Azure Hosting Server In China

Tags: azure, server

Hi I am trying to create an azure server in china from the united kingdom. All I want to know if this is possible. I have read that you need to create the server from the Azure China Site?

I don't speak chinese which means I have to tanslate every webpage I go onto which is a bit annoying and some text isnt translated.

When starting a trial the first step is to add a phone number and without it you cant progress, but since I dont have a chinese phone number I am unable to get past this. This is why I am asking whether or not it is possible to host a chinese server from te UK.

When Im on the UK/American Azure Site and I need to select the county I am from the information text tells me this

*"Choose the primary country or region where you or your organization will use Microsoft Azure. You cannot change this country later. This setting determines the data center closest to you."*

Does this mean if I choose United Kingdom I will never be able to host a server in china?

Thanks for any help it is much appreciated

Comment: Yes. You need a chinese azure subscription. similar to us gov, germany  subscriptions azure china is a separate entity by itself. the payment options are different and also the version and feature availability may lag when compare to azure US, UK regions.

Comment: @Aravind I am unable to create a china subscription because the first step involves verifying a phone number and you are only able to enter chinese ones. [Azure China](https://www.azure.cn/) if you go to that link and click start trial you will see what I am talking about

Comment: it  makes sense since a chinese stakeholder would be involved in hosting stuff in azure china. Just check if the services that you are planning to use are available in azure china. then do a prototype in azure UK and once u have all things to setup china cloud you can deploy the applications, services there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is why I am asking whether or not it is possible to host a
>   chinese server from te UK.

No. You can't host a server in China Data Center (DC) from UK using your UK Azure Subscription. In order to make use of China DC so that you can host resources there, you would need to have an Azure Subscription in China. Your regular Azure Subscription does not give you access to that DC. This is same as access to Azure US Government DCs.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me. Is there no possible way of creating a chinese server using azure? I am only asking so I can get as close to the live situation as possible and I need to test it from china to see if it work since they lock everything down over there.

Comment: Only if you have an Azure Subscription in China. If proximity to your users is a requirement, you can possibly host a server in Hong Kong or Singapore.

Comment: If I host a server from Hong Kong would it have all the restrictions that china has on the internet

Comment: `If I host a server from Hong Kong would it have all the restrictions that china has on the internet` --> I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Ok Thank you for all the help to host a server from Hong Kong do I just create my azure account in the United Kingdom and then I get an option to host from Hong Kong?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do so.